# How to print most frequent lines of file in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, file, unix, terminal

I have file with lines:

```
<host>\t<ip>\n
```

and I need to print first 5 most frequent IPs. How can I do that?

For example, if I needed to print 3 most frequent IPs from this file:

```
host1   192.168.0.26
host2   192.168.0.26
host3   192.168.0.23
host4   192.168.0.24
host5   192.168.0.26
host6   192.168.0.26
host7   192.168.0.25
host8   192.168.0.26
host9   192.168.0.26
host18  192.168.0.22
host22  192.168.0.22
host24  192.168.0.23
```

I would print:
192.168.0.26
192.168.0.22
192.168.0.23

Comment: There are many ways. Try to give a sample input file, desired output... and, of course, what you tried so far.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at SuperUser? This site is for writing software.

Comment: `here-output-your-ips | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -k1 | head -n 5`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Note that it returns 5 lines, even if there are 10 IPs with the same frequency.

```
cut -f2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | head -n5
```